# Yii2 Fragment Caching for GridView

Tags: caching, yii2

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-fragment.html

My code is:

```
$dependency = [
    'class' => 'yii\caching\DbDependency',
    'sql' => 'SELECT MAX(updated_at) FROM converter_operator_device;',
];

$variations = [
   [\Yii::$app->request->absoluteUrl, \Yii::$app->user->isGuest],
];

if ($this->beginCache('table-connection',['dependency' => $dependency, 'variations' => $variations])) {                        
   // here gridView.
}
```

When the fragment cached then filters of GridView doesn't work, because need js GridView. How fix?

**UPD:**
I add before cache the code:

```
$this->registerJs("$('#table-connection').yiiGridView({'filterUrl':document.URL,'filterSelector':'#table-connection-filters input, #table-connection-filters select'})");
GridViewAsset::register($this);
```

This works, but **how track the cache load?**

Comment: Have you solved it?I have the same problem

Comment: @Mahsa no solution was found and had to abandon GridView with fragment caching.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting one :), try having an else after the if that would register the needed JS. So if your dependencies fail you include the GridView, if they do not fail you have the HTML with the included JS file to make it work.

Comment: I tried, but the js script is dynamic. See https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/grid/GridView.php#L281 . I tried `$('#table-connection').yiiGridView('applyFilter');` but get error with related begin init options... Easier to disable caching and go the other way. But this is not the solution :)

Comment: How track the cache load? Because i get dublicate js code (my in cache and native js when cache doesn't load)

Answer (score 0):

registerJs is perform in Gridview function "run()" 
maybe you can seprate gridview like below :

```
$grid = new GridView([
  'layout'=> "{summary}",
]);
echo $grid->run();

if ($this->beginCache('id')) {                        
  echo $grid->renderItems();
  $this->endCache();
}
```

In my case I only enable sorting in gridview, it work for me.